# local variables in C

Tags: c, local-variables

when I try the following code in visual studio it gives me 45 but when I run it in online compilers some give me an error and some give me 0.I was expecting that they all give me an error.how is that they are not?!
thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *f(int *a)
{
    *a = 23;
    int b = 45;
    return &b;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 2;
    int *p;
    p = f(&i);

    printf("The return value of function f: %d\n\n", *p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are returning a reference to a stack allocated variable - this is **very** bad!! Don't do this, this can cause tons of nasty, hidden bugs

Comment: Even if you are getting correct value in visual studio, this is wrong. You don't get any error since function's return type is int* and you are returning an int*.

Comment: @MayurK Just because the re is *no* correct value..

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

```
return &b;
```

You are returning a pointer to a local variable that is going out of scope - hence the pointer will be invalid

If you get an error depends on the various settings for that compiler

Comment: I guess that's why she expected the compilers to give an error. So it does not answer the question.

Comment: The compiler doesn't give an error, as there is no error in this specific line and it is perfectly legal...

Comment: @EugeneSh.- Just because you do not get caught does not mean that it is legal. The thief on that occasion was lucky

Comment: @EdHeal Returning an address of a local variable is perfectly legal. Dereferencing it is UB.